# Equivalence Relation Proof Writing

Tags: proof-writing, equivalence-relations

Consider the following example:

let x,y $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and let $R$ be a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $xRy$ if $|x|=|y|$. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$.

Upon proving this statement, I was just curious if it was okay to approach it as an *if-then* statement? For example, when proving the symmetric property I approached it as follows in the first few lines of my proof:

If $|x|=|y|$ then $xRy$

as in, $|x|=|y|$ implies that $xRy$.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, how does that if-then statement relate to the symmetric property?

Comment: My apologies, I just edited my question. Care to take another look? If not I'll attempt to elaborate more. @79037662

Comment: Sure, virtually all statements in math can be considered as an if-then statement.

Comment: Still not clear ... Yes, we have that if $|x|=|y|$ then $xRy$, because that is part of the definition of $R$ ...  is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes (: ! thank you - sorry for the confusion. If you wish to edit my post to make it clear for future viewers, feel free. That answers my question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let x,y $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and let $R$ be a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $xRy$ if $|x|=|y|$. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Upon proving this statement, I was just curious if it was okay to approach it as an *if-then* statement? ...
>
> If $|x|=|y|$ then $xRy$

Yes, when it defines $R$ and says that:

> $xRy$ if $|x|=|y|$

That is the exact same thing as:

> If $|x|=|y|$ then $xRy$

That is, 'P if Q' is the same as 'If Q, then P'